# 24 V input, three 5 V outputs DC-DC buck converter design

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, converter, output, multiple

I would like to make a DC-DC buck converter which has 24 V input and three 5 V outputs, but a typical buck converter circuits have only one output. How to change it to three outputs without an extra chip? Is it even possible?

[image]

Comment: Do you really need three independent outputs?  The output of a normal single-output DC-DC converter can be split to feed any number of loads (with due consideration of load current requirements).

Comment: I am making 3 cell lipo battery balanced charger. for supply each cell I need 5v output, each output controlled by arduino so i can control which cell must be charge first. so is it possible to single output to feed 3 cells.

Comment: `3 cell lipo battery balanced charger…` `course work…can't just buy` Do not comment comments asking for clarification or complementary information: update your post (including title). If you want to charge a 3S battery and have access to 24 V power, state it that way - more parameters on battery, power source, environment, skill level, budget welcome. (Quote the problem literally as a block quote: asking for 5 V to charge a Li-po cell is a bit off.)

Comment: Unless the cells are no longer connected in series, a which point you don't have a balance charger, just a bunch of chargers, you need isolation between each output. A buck converter does not provide any isolation.

Comment: Perhaps this [document](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/whp/how-reconfigure-buck-converter-multiple-outputs) discussion multiple outputs will be helpful for you to think about the overall architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmh you are up for a ride here!

**(1)** In general it is possible to build a 'Single-Input, Triple-Output' DC/DC.

But without any IC - if you see at least FETs and their driving circuits as ICs - it will only be possible with 'extreme engineering'.

**(2)** Judging from your question - be aware: mis-interpretation can happen - i would say: You are best off with using of-the-shelf parts.

I had a quick look at my favourite suppliers [Digikey DC/DCs](https://www.digikey.de/de/products/filter/dc-dc-wandler/922) and [Mouser DC/DCs](https://www.mouser.de/c/power/dc-dc-converters/non-isolated-dc-dc-converters/). I guess you could use e.g. three of these [Single 24V/5V 5W DC/DC](https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/xp-power/VR10S05/13147713) in parallel - so one for each of your 5V Rails.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. This is my course work so I can not just buy it. I need schematic so i can simulate it pls help me to find real schematic and also sorry for bad english

Comment: (Can't use your product hyperlink: 403 forbidden.)

Comment: @greybeard all three links open okay from my location, perhaps your browser/network has a different problem?

Comment: (Works *if* I open digikey.de before - some cookie woodoo?!) Three terminal converters aren't isolated output, which would be required here (well, at least for but one of them).

Comment: @greybeard I noticed a few things with digikey myself in the past... The parametric search is in my opinion unbeaten, but there are problems to say at least.